# Swift remove item in array

Tags: arrays, swift, swifty-json

I have a Problem with SwityJson and removing an Element of an Array

For further Datahandling  i must remove some Elements.

here my Code

```
self.jsonObj = JSON(value)

//Filtern 

for i in 0 ..< self.jsonObj["customer"].count {

    if self.jsonObj["customer"][i]["Group_A"].string == "Mr Abcde" 
            || self.jsonObj["customer"][i]["Group_A"].string == "Mr Bcde" 
            || self.jsonObj["custome"][i]["Group_B"].string == "Mr Abcde" 
            || self.jsonObj["customer"][i]["Group_B"].string == "Mr Bcde" 
    {
        self.jsonObj["customer"].arrayObject?.removeAtIndex(i)
    }
}
```

Now the Problem: If running the Code not all found Element are removed. 
I think that looping through all Elements is too fast. There is noch Time for the removing Task?!
How can I handle it. Looping...found something...stop looping...remove Item...start looping..

By making the If-Statement for three Times all is fine an all found Elements are removed, but hey, this is not what i want.

Or is it possible to filter the Array an then say

```
filterdData = jsonObj
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
            //Filtern 

 for i in 0 ..< self.jsonObj["customer"].count {
      let groupA = self.jsonObj["customer"][i]["Group_A"].string
      let groupB = self.jsonObj["customer"][i]["Group_B"].string

            if  groupA == "Mr Abcde" || groupA == "Mr Bcde" || groupB == "Mr Abcde" || groupB == "Mr Bcde"{
                    self.jsonObj["customer"].rawArray.removeAtIndex(i)
            }                   
 }
```

Not only does this have less calls to the JSON object(potentially saving speed) but it also uses rawArray instead of arrayObject which writes directly the array instead of going through the arrayObject to the rawArray.

Comment: Sorry, it's the same Result..:(
Not all found Elements are removes

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're changing the count that terminates the loop from within the loop. You need to not do that, perhaps using filter or a related approach instead

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend normalizing the data before modifying it. But failing that you could try this:

```
let filteredJson = self.jsonObj["customer"].filter { elem  in
  !(["Mr Abcde", "Mr Bcde"].contains(elem.["Group_A"].string) ||
    ["Mr Abcde", "Mr Bcde"].contains(elem.["Group_B"].string))
}
```

and then use the `filteredJson` constant.

Comment: good idea, but how can i convert filteredJson to the JSON Format??